# Android Service classes

Tags: android

why it is not showing me a messageboxdialog when the Service is being activated.

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    player.start();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    AlarmService.this.onDestroy();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });


}
```

The Toast is appearing the sound is being played only the showdialog is not comming, why ?

Comment: You cannot create Dialogs from a Service. Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126868/showing-an-ok-dialog-box-from-a-service-receiver-in-android

Comment: What i want is to show me a button when the service is running to stop it,So do you think from Service I have to create Intent and to call another Activity which that activity call onDestroy() method will stop the service?

Comment: You don't need the activity at all. The service has a method, **stopService(Intent)**. Just call that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29

Comment: I am making an alarm clock and when the alarm comes there is homescreen how to stop it ??

Comment: how to make an option when the alarm comes with an button to stop it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `builder.create()` to create your `AlertDialog`, then `show()` on the dialog to display it.

However, if this is a Service, you won't be able to display the dialog directly. Have a look at this question for how to show a Dialog from within a Service: [Alert dialog from Android service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599563/android-alert-dialog-from-service)

Comment: You could just call show(). Create will automatically be called then.

Comment: I want to show it when the Service starts, for ex in this case my service plays a sound, I want to stop it by AlerDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `create()` on your Builder to create a AlertDialog which can then be shown by a call to `show()`. See [the dialogues guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for more info on this topic.